# Center text above font awesome icon?

Tags: css, alignment, font-awesome

How can I horizontally and vertically center text above font awesome icon?

Example code:

```
<div>
    <i class="icon-circle"></i>
    <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering FontAwesome icons vertically and horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642953/centering-fontawesome-icons-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: ...he wants to center the text, not the icon.

Comment: Could you be more specific? (1) Can you switch the order of the `<i>` and `<span>` elements? (2) Can you specify a height for the `<i>` element? (3) Is there a height assigned to the parent `<div>`?  The response to these questions will influence the choice of possible answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bootstrap 2.3 I achieved it like this:

```
<span class="icon-stack" style="text-align:center;">
    <i class="icon-circle icon-2x"></i>
    <span class="icon-stack"><strong>Some text</strong></span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just  set display:table-cell, vertical-align: middle and text-align: center to the div

CSS

```
div{
display: table-cell;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
p {
  <!-- set the paragraph position as absolute -->
       vertical-align: bottom;
       display: inline-block;  
       position: absolute;
        }
   
i {
    <!-- set the image position relatively -->  
      vertical-align: top;
      margin-top: 6%;
      margin-left: 0.7%;
      position: relative;
        }
```

```html
    <head>
       <!--let's assume u chose the fa-camera-retro icon-->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">  
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="icon_labeled">`
           <p>Truc</p>
           <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>        
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="content">
         <span>text</span>
         <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
     width: 200px;
     height: 80px;
     background-color: #ddd;
     text-align: center;
     display: table;
}
div .content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div .content span {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63ovh9xk/